# EscapeString Class for MySQL and JSON Using the Builder Pattern

Tags: vba

This class is being used to build some complex strings JSON and MySql.

Note: I'm not using the JSon converter because is difficult to create the structures the at that I want them and MySQL require extra escape characters.

At a later date, I may consider upgrading the class using Regular Expressions or CreateObject("System.Collections.StringBuilder").  ANy advice on either of these methods would be appreciated.

### EscapeString:Class

```
Attribute VB_Name = "EscapeString"
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Ext_KEY = "Rubberduck" ,"Predeclared Class Module"
Option Explicit
'@PredeclaredId

Private Type TMembers
    Content As String
End Type
Private this As TMembers

Public Property Get Create(ByVal Content As String) As EscapeString
    With New EscapeString
        .Content = Content
        Set Create = .Self
    End With
End Property

Public Property Get Self() As EscapeString
    Set Self = Me
End Property

Public Property Get EscapeMySQL() As EscapeString
    Rem https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html
    Rem \\  A backslash (\) character
    Rem \"  A double quote (") character
    Rem \b  A backspace character
    Rem \n  A newline (linefeed) character
    Rem \r  A carriage return character
    Rem \t  A tab character
    Rem EscapeJSON escapes all the referenced characters to this point
    IIf False, Me.EscapeJSON, ""
    
    Rem \0  An ASCII NUL (X'00') character
    If InStr(Content, Chr(0)) > 0 Then Content = Replace(Content, Chr(0), "\0 ")
    Rem \'  A single quote (') character
    If InStr(Content, "'") > 0 Then Content = Replace(Content, "'", "\'")
    Rem \Z  ASCII 26 (Control+Z); see note following the table
    If InStr(Content, Chr(26)) > 0 Then Content = Replace(Content, Chr(26), "\Z ")
    Rem \%  A % character; see note following the table
    If InStr(Content, "%") > 0 Then Content = Replace(Content, "%", "\%")
    Rem \_  A _ character; see note following the table
    If InStr(Content, "_") > 0 Then Content = Replace(Content, "_", "\_")
    
    Set EscapeMySQL = Self
End Property

Public Property Get EscapeJSON() As EscapeString
    Rem https://bettersolutions.com/vba/strings-characters/ascii-characters.htm
    Rem Backslash to be replaced with \\
    If InStr(Content, "\") > 0 Then Content = Replace(Content, "\", "\\")
           
    Rem Backspace to be replaced with \b
    If InStr(Content, Chr(8)) > 0 Then Content = Replace(Content, Chr(8), "\b")
    
     Rem Newline to be replaced with \n
    If InStr(Content, vbNewLine) > 0 Then Content = Replace(Content, vbNewLine, "\n")
   
    Rem Form feed to be replaced with \f
    If InStr(Content, vbLf) > 0 Then Content = Replace(Content, vbLf, "\f")
   
     Rem Tab to be replaced with \t
    If InStr(Content, vbTab) > 0 Then Content = Replace(Content, vbTab, "\t")
    
    Rem Double quote to be replaced with \"
    If InStr(Content, Chr(34)) > 0 Then Content = Replace(Content, Chr(34), "\" & Chr(34))
    Set EscapeJSON = Self
End Property

Public Function ToString(Optional ContentWrapper As String = "") As String
        ToString = ContentWrapper & this.Content & ContentWrapper
End Function

Public Property Get Content() As String
    Content = this.Content
End Property

Public Property Let Content(ByVal Value As String)
    this.Content = Value
End Property
```

### Examples

[image: Examples]

Comment: N.b. I opened an [issue](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/2851) on highlight.js about the `REM` syntax highlighting issue

Comment: @Greedo I never noticed.  I switched to using `Rem` because I think that an overabundance of apostrophes is obnoxious.